# Including large amount of figures and flalign equations

Tags: floats, equations, flalign

I have a large .tex file about (7500 lines) containing text and including figures and flalign equation. This file is meant to illustrate each of my 250 variables. So the structure of this file is as follow:

```
\section{industry-name}
  \subsection{variable 1 in this industry}
   some commentary
   \begin{figure}
      \includegraphics{variable-1.png}
   \end{figure}

equation of variable 1
\begin{flalign}
equation 
\end{flalign}
```

The indentation in the LaTex is just for your see the structure. Then this layout go on for hundreds of variables.

When input this file and compile the documentation. I got the following error:

[image]

I am sure it works if I only include 20 variables that is about 700 lines in the file. But apparently does not work for a huge amount...

I reckoned the problem is like including more pngs at the same time in LaTex, you need to add *\clearpage* or *\FloatBarrier* to work. But I have tried this option, it still produced the error.

I understand that *flalign* to left align the equation doesn't seem to be used very often, but this is required for our document.

I wonder anyone have ideas to solve it?

Many thanks

Comment: As always on the cite, please provide a full minimal example that others can copy and test as is. Sniplets like this is not something we can test. For the images you can used the ones included in the `mwe` package or use `\rule{4cm}{4cm}`

Comment: are you sure you want to use floating figures here I would have thought just using `\includegraphics` was more suitable however this will be unrelated to the amsmath error. You should be able to make an example document that only has the math and doesn't require any figures.

Comment: And if you used simple `equation` environments, using the `fleqn` option for your \documentclass?